# Macro not running in Microsoft Word 2016 for Mac even though template is working

Tags: macos, macros, templates, microsoft-word-2016

I can't seem to run the following macro:
[image: AttatchVerbatim_Macro]

It gives me the following error message:[image: Error_Message]

However, my template seems to be in the correct place for Word 2016 on Mac:
[image: File_Path]

Also, the launch screen for Word 2016 seems to recognize the "Debate" template and allow me to create documents from it:[image: Word_2016_Launch_Screen]

Additional notes,

when I click Organizer while "AttachVerbatim" is selected in the "Macros" screen, the following window pops up: 
[Organizer_Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeC1h.png)

Also, when I click "edit", the following window pops up:
[Visual Basic Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEcwv.png)

This macro is part of the following application: https://paperlessdebate.com/verbatim/

Verbatim adds a new template called "Debate.dotm"

Also, it is worth nothing I "verbatimized" the normal template, which is one of the features in verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your Startup Disk's name to `Macintosh HD`.

The macro expects your startup disk to have this exact name. See the code excerpt from the macro (AttachVerbatim):

```
    If AppleScriptTask("Verbatim.scpt", "FileExists", "Macintosh HD" & Replace(Replace(Application.NormalTemplate.Path & "/Debate.dotm", ".localized", ""), "/", ":")) = "false" Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Debate.dotm not found in your Templates folder - it must be installed correctly to attach it."
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

---

Please note that you may need to re-install the template. In this case remove these files first if they exist:

- ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Templates/Debate.dotm
- ~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Word/Verbatim.scpt
- ~/Library/Preferences/Verbatim.plist (this file may not exist)

Comment: Would it be possible for me to edit the code in the macro?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: How would I do that?